# Redirect to other location

Tags: .htaccess

I have the current setup where my file system looks like this

/var/www/blog.example.com/v1/project.php

To access project.php you go to blog.example.com/project, now I've also added a GET which is a title.

Instead of going to blog.example.com/project?title=This Title I want it to be something like blog.example.com/project/This Title

How may I accomplish that setup? Current .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^project/(.*)$ v1/project.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(v1)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}v1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ v1/$1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-d
RewriteRule ^project/([\w-]+)$ v1/project.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```
# turn off MultiViews to avoid conflicts
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# handle /project/abcd URI
RewriteRule ^project/([^/]+)/?$ v1/project.php?title=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# add .php extension intrnally
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/v1/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ v1/$1.php [L]

# forward everything to v1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!v1/)(.*)$ v1/$1 [L,NC]
```